# Is __class__ implementation modified in IPython with respect to Python?

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to compare `__class__` function in Python and IPython with `type()` function in both and wondering if below difference in behavior is because of `__class__` modification in IPython w.r.t Python.

Python

```
>>> [].__class__
<class 'list'>
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
```

IPython

```
In [2]: [].__class__
Out[2]: list

In [3]: type([])
Out[3]: list
```

But with print it still seems to be referring to Python's `__class__`

Python

```
>>> print(type([]))
<class 'list'>
```

IPython

```
In [4]: print(type([]))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it is IPython's `sys.displayhook` that is modified: `list` still refers to `<class 'list'>`, it is just printed differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where the magic happens:

```
In [1] import sys
In [2] sys.displayhook
Out[2]: <IPython.terminal.prompts.RichPromptDisplayHook at 0x7f6c42b08190>
```

vs.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.displayhook
<built-in function displayhook>
```

The object being displayed (`list`, or `<class 'list'>`) is the same object. Using [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), IPython modifies how it is displayed in the interactive REPL.